# Don't allow to read specific key yo read in firebase database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: Don't allow to read specific key to read in firebase database]

I this database i have a reference "user app/profile"
in the user app/profile in the profile path it has uid and each uid contains user data but i want to don't allow anyone to read pw key value because it contains private data of user but i search every where but i can't find any way

Comment: Welcome to SO. 1) Please do not store passwords in the clear; encrypt them if you must store them in Firebase. 2) [Firebase Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security) are designed to allow/disallow/verify data to be read/written. Please read the guide 3) SO is not a code writing service - we can help with existing code (or rules) but not create them for you. Please write some code, create some rules and when you get stuck, ask a question here. Oh, rules are also dependent on the queries you want to run, please include those.

Comment: There is no way to allow the user read access to all-but-one property of a node. Once the user can read a node, it can read all data under that node too.

You'll want to separate the public data for a user from their private data, as shown in the questions in I linked